# NSMutableAttributedString contains NSMutableAttributedString and NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley_0.png"];
attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22);
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment] mutableCopy];
[aLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Using code above, `aLabel` can display a image(*smiley_0.png*) correctly, now I want to append a string to the `aLabel`, any idea?

Comment: Did you try appending?

Comment: @Wain thanks, I tried but some other problem make it display wrong,now it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use appendAttributedString of NSMutableAttributedString to your attributedString as below

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley_0.png"];
attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22);
NSMutableAttributedString *appendedString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"yourString"];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment] mutableCopy];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:appendedString];
[aLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Hope it helps you....!